# Failed to resolve Android dependency 'com.github.ViksaaSkool:AwesomeSplash:v1.0.0'

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies

When I tried to declare depencency `com.github.ViksaaSkool:AwesomeSplash:v1.0.0` in my Android project, I get the following error

```
Failed to resolve: 'com.github.ViksaaSkool:AwesomeSplash:v1.0.0'
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF93x.png]

Answer (score 0):

add `maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io'}`  to build.gradle(project) to be like this :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub- 
projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io'}
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

it's worked for me.